# WooCommerce - Add content on the thank you page by the shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to place my own content (in my case a shortcode) on the thank you page at WooCommerce after completing the order, which depends on the shipping method.

So for example:
Shipping Method 1: Content 1
Shipping Method 2: Content 2
Shipping Method 3: No content

I have already found something for text [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829609/adding-custom-message-on-thank-you-page-by-shipping-method), but i dont get the shortcode inserted. Alternatively I have tested what works with the shortcode [here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-text-thank-page/), where the dependency on the shipping method is missing.

Maybe someone can help me to implement this.
Ideally the content should be above the table with the order information.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the way you added the `shortcode` to the `thank you` text can be the issue.

See the following `shortcode` function called **avengers** which i created for demo.

```
function call_avangers( $atts ){
    return "<p>Avengers . . . .  Assemble !!!</p>";
}
add_shortcode( 'avengers', 'call_avangers' );
```

You can display this shortcode in thank you page using the below function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 20, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_shipping_method() == 'your_shipping_method_here' ) {
        $text .= do_shortcode('[avengers]');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

The basic thing is you have to call `do_shortcode('your_shortcode_name')`